# Error in spyOn toHaveBeenCalled in model testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test Jasmine's toHaveBeenCalled() matcher.
My src:

```
function myModel (){
}

  myModel.prototype.getObjcts = function (){
    return DS.findAll('obj', {});
  }
```

And Jasmine test:

```
 describe('findAll', function(){
      it('check calling findAll()', function(){
        spyOn(DS, 'findAll');
        myModel.getObjcts();
        expect(DS.findAll('obj', {})).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
```

But all the time I get an error

> Expected a spy, but got undefined

Please, help me to understand where is a problem

Answer (score 0):

1. You should instantiate a new object of type myModel
2. Your expectation calls DS.finadAll again instead of checking the spy.

Here is the complete solution:

```
window.DS = {
    findAll: function (param1, param2) {}
};


function myModel() {}

myModel.prototype.getObjcts = function () {
    return DS.findAll('obj', {});
};


describe('findAll', function () {
    it('check calling findAll()', function () {
        spyOn(DS, 'findAll');
        var testApp = new myModel();
        testApp.getObjcts();
        expect(DS.findAll).toHaveBeenCalledWith('obj', {});
    });
});
```

You can find a runnable solution in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/vavdzvj3/)